# How would one find the number of spanning trees in a unlabled graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How would I go about finding the number of spanning trees? Is there a tech[image]unique to do this?

Comment: What does _minimal_ mean when you don't seem to have any edge weights?

Comment: @HenningMakholm accidentally wrote minimal in

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90950/finding-the-number-of-spanning-trees-of-a-graph-g

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary graph, you would use something like [Kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem). But with a graph like yours with lots of symmetry one may hope to find a clever shortcut specific to that graph.

For example, consider the 9 "outer" edges of the graph, and consider which of them are *not* in the spanning tree. It is clear that *at most* one of them can be missing in each of the squares, or some vertices would be cut off. So we can do an analysis by cases:

- If *none* of the 9 outer edges are missing, then they form a cycle. Impossible.
- If *one* of the 9 outer edges are missing, then the remaining 8 form a spanning tree together.
- If *two* of the 9 outer edges are missing, they must be in different squares, and *exactly one* of the corresponding "inner" eges must be added to the spanning tree.
- If *three* of the 9 outer edges are missing, then we must choose *exactly two* of the inner edges to complete the tree.

---

Alternatively: Exactly one of the three corners of the triangle must have the property that the path between the two *other* corners (along the spanning tree) passes through it.

Each of the squares adjacent to that corner can have a spanning tree selected in $4$ ways, and then there are $3$ ways to connect the two outer vertices in the last square.