The number of spanning trees of an unlabeled graph involving four heptagons
Given the following unlabeled graph (link), how many spanning trees does it have? The graph is basically four heptagons, each having exactly one common vertex with its top/bottom and left/right heptagon. For example, the upper-left heptagon has one vertex in common with the upper-right one, and another (different) vertex in common with the bottom-left one.

My Attempt:
I've tried simplifying the graph first. Instead of heptagons, I tried to use triangles. Drawing out the possible spanning trees, I believe there are a total of $14$ different (non-isomorphic) spanning trees in such a structure. (This is the simplified graph with triangles instead of heptagons.)
However, even with this simplified graph, I don't have much of an idea of how to count the number of spanning trees [short of actually drawing them all out, which I've done but a) I am not sure if I haven't missed any and b) drawing them is infeasible for the original heptagon graph]. I've thought about the fact that the spanning tree should have $8 - 1 = 7$ edges, and there are $12$ edges in total in the graph, so maybe $\binom{12}{7}$ ways to pick out 7 edges, then minus the 7-edged subgraphs that have cycles. But then again, finding the number of 7-edged subgraphs that have cycles is an entirely different problem.
Note that I'm completely focusing on the simplified, triangle version of the graph instead of the original heptagon version; because I believe that if I manage to solve this simplified case instead, the heptagon case wouldn't be too different. However, I'm completely stumped. Note that the matrix-tree theorem is not intended to be used in this problem.

You need to remove $5$ edges. How many with one edge removed from the square? With two edges removed from the square? And so on...

Relevant post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/123960/578498
